# How can I monitor network in OS X?

Tags: macos, network

I met a problem recently.

Sometimes the Google shows me a page says that my computer is sending frequent requests to Google so that I must enter the number in the picture to continue to use Google's services.

Obviously, I would not do such thing.

The applications installed in my Mac are all from trusted sources(e.g. official websites).

I have no idea 'who' is doing such thing.

How can I monitor the network to find out the 'worngdoer'.

Comment: What connection to the Internet do you use? If it was some kind of shared network with a proxy for multiple nodes, it might not necessarily be the problem with your computer.

Comment: Yep, I've seen this if there's too many hosts on a single IP (NAT), especially if everyone searches the same thing all at once, like in a classroom.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing netstat in terminal.app
First I would type `man netstat` to get a better understanding of how it works and what it is capable of and what the results mean.

Try searching a tutorial about the command on stackexchange or youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the reason.

Since I am in China, for some formidable reasons, I use the Shadowsocks with a **public account** to connect to the Google.

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but to your problem.